# Solrj - SQL Query with SQL Editor

Tags: sql, solr, solrj

I am working with Solr Cloud. The Solr version is 4.10.3. I use the following version of solrj: solr-solrj-6.0.0.jar. I have implemented the driver Software
to Squirrel or DBVisualizer.
I am able to connect to the cluster over zookeeper. After that I tried to query
my collection and get the following error:

Error: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: --> http://myserver:8983/solr/cloudera_tutorial_tweets_shard2_replica1/: An exception has occurred on the server, refer to server log for details.
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0

I am not able to find more log information on my servers in solr log.
So, maybe someone can give me some advice for further debugging.
Could it be possible that my version of solr is to old for using sql-queries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your Solr version is (way) too old. [The SQL interface](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/parallel-sql-interface.html) (/sql, named ParallelSQL) [was introduced with Solr 6](http://yonik.com/solr-6/).